# PyUSB does not get response from XBox One Controller

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyusb, xbox-one

I am trying to read from a Xbox One Controller responses from its keys. I have already found its IdVendor and IdProduct using

```
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
```

This controller works fine on Ubuntu since I use it in Steam, so there is no problem of drivers.

When I get the device object and try to read from it I get only 0s:

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=XXX, idProduct=XXX)
interface = 0
endpoint = dev[0][(0,0)][0]
if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(interface) is True: 
  dev.detach_kernel_driver(interface)
  usb.util.claim_interface(dev, interface)
collected = 0
attempts = 50
while collected < attempts :
    try:
        data = dev.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress,endpoint.wMaxPacketSize)
        collected += 1
        print data

array('B', [0, 0, 0, ...]
array('B', [0, 0, 0, ...]
array('B', [0, 0, 0, ...]
etc
```

I tried to filter responses with all 0s but I have never recieved anything.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!